# Record video Without Preview

Tags: android, video-capture

I want to start recording video from camera when I click on lyt and stop recording when click it again. this code makes "myVideo.mp4" file but it is not play able.
also I don't want to show any preview.
any one can help me?

Activity Main :

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

MediaRecorder rec;
static Camera camera;
boolean       isRecording = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt);

    rec = new MediaRecorder();

    lyt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (isRecording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                Log.e("TEST", "befor stop");
                rec.stop(); // stop the recording
                Log.e("TEST", "stop");
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                camera.lock(); // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                isRecording = false;
            } else {
                // initialize video camera
                if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                    // now you can start recording
                    Log.e("TEST", "befor start");
                    rec.start();
                    Log.e("TEST", "start");

                    // inform the user that recording has started
                    isRecording = true;
                } else {
                    // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                    // inform user
                }
            }

        }
    });

    //    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, VideoCapture.class);
    //    startActivity(intent);
}


private void releaseMediaRecorder() {

    if (rec != null) {
        //  rec.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
        rec.release(); // release the recorder object
        rec = null;
        camera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        Log.e("TEST", "released");
    }
}


/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "Camera is not avalable : " + e);
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}


private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

    camera = getCameraInstance();
    rec = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    camera.unlock();
    rec.setCamera(camera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    rec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    rec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    rec.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/" + "myVideo.mp4");

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        rec.prepare();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252172/android-how-to-initialize-mediarecorder-without-a-valid-surface-for-video-previ

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It works fine. A preview is showing, but you can not see it. If you find tutorial how to record video without activity, please, post here. I'm trying to do this.

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

CameraActivity.java

```
 public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    public void onLinearClick(View v) {
        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            //                            setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
            isRecording = false;
        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording

                try {
                    mMediaRecorder.start();

                    // inform the user that recording has started
                    //                                setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                    isRecording = true;

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
           File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
 mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    /** A basic Camera preview class */
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
            // reformatting changes here

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_camera.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onLinearClick">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```